# Shortcut to move to next new content (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, cells

I'd like to know if there is a shortcut to move to and select the last cell in a row or coumn with the same content as the current cell. I.e. ctrl + arrow moves to the edge of the data array, but I'd like to move, and ideally select all, to the edge of an array of the same displayed content (i.e. the same results, but not necessarily the same formula).

e.g.  I have a column with 100 cells with "1", followed by 100 cells with "2" then 100 cells with "3".  If I've selected one of the cells with "2" the shortcut would select the last cell with "2", just before the "3".

It would be great if the answer could deal with the differences between the displayed result of the cells and the content of the cells (i.e. the cells of the column which display "2" actually has cells saying "=1+1" and "=3-1").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not such a function built in to Excel but you could make one.

[Excel 2010 Keyboard Shortcuts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-2010-HP010342494.aspx), [Excel 2013 Keyboard Shortcuts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-HA102772370.aspx?CTT=1), [Excel Online Keyboard Shortcuts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office-online-help/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-online-HA010378329.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010380212)

To simulate whatever keyboard shortcut you want, you can use VBA using the [Application.OnKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461%28v=office.15%29.aspx) method to assign a keyboard combination to a macro.
The idea is as follows:
In the Workbook_Open event, assign keyboard commands to macros
In the Workbook_BeforeClose event, assign the same commands to nothing (reset to default)
In a module, write the subroutines you want to run for those keyboard commands

Now, whenever you open the workbook, your selected keyboard commands will make macros run that will do whatever you want. This is good for way more than just moving around the sheet. In my example, I assigned the keys CTRL+D and CTRL+U for Down and Up but you pick whatever makes the most sense to you.
If you want these keyboard commands to work for every file, the premise is the same except that you save them in your personal macro workbook instead.

I can't figure out how to attach files so here's the code. (Note that this code is rough and quick. I wanted the simplest example, not the most robust code.)

In the "ThisWorkbook" object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "^d", "findLastOfThis"
    Application.OnKey "^u", "findFirstOfThis"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.OnKey "^d"
    Application.OnKey "^u"
End Sub
```

In a module:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub findLastOfThis()
    Dim val As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    val = ActiveCell.Value
    c = ActiveCell.Column
    For r = ActiveCell.Row To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Cells(r, c).Value <> val Then Exit For
    Next
    r = r - 1
    Cells(r, c).Activate
End Sub

Private Sub findFirstOfThis()
    Dim val As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    val = ActiveCell.Value
    c = ActiveCell.Column
    For r = ActiveCell.Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(r, c).Value <> val Then Exit For
    Next
    r = r + 1
    Cells(r, c).Activate
End Sub
```